# Finding RSS and R-Squared

Tags: python, linear-regression

am pretty new to all this (so please be merciful)

so I've imported a csv file into python as shown below:

```
data = pd.read_csv("sales.csv")
data.head(10)
```

[csv data in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2VtX.png)

and I then fit a linear regression model on the sales variable, using the variables as shown in the results as predictors. the results are summarised below:

```
model_linear = smf.ols('sales ~ month + weekend + holiday + prod_function + prod_regime + prod_listprice + discount + stockout', data=data).fit()
print(model_linear.summary())
```

[summary of regression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bp5q.png)

and given the above, I want to find the RSS and R-squared of the model.
this is what I did:

```
RSS = np.sum(model_linear.resid**2)
print(RSS)
model_linear.rsquared
```

is this the right approach to doing this?

Comment: If manual calculation is OK, with  "error = predicted - actual", you could use "RSS = numpy.sum(numpy.square(error))" and also for R-squared (R2) you can use "R2 = 1.0 - (numpy.var(error) / numpy.var(actual))".